# SQL Server openrowset assumes incorrect field types

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I use `openrowset` to import data from `.csv` into tables. Strangely enough, when the `.csv` does not contain text, the table on the SQL Server side is properly created with int/date types. However, when there are columns with text, the tables are created with all `nvarchar(250)`.

Is this normal? Thanks

**UPDATE
The act of opening the .csv in excel, making a minor change, closing and saving the file via the "XXX may contain features that are not compatible with the csv format" prompt resolves this problem ...**

Comment: How else would it import? You can't put text in an int column... The database engine looks to find instances of text in the column, and if it does, sets the column meta to a varchar format. This is consistent across all methods of importing csv data into SQL Server.

Comment: i have columns that are all text and other columns that are all ints.  when both types of columns are present, openrowset assumes that they are all of type nvarchar when some columns are obviously all ints.

Comment: You can use a format file if you want to explicitly declare each column data type. Post an example of the code you're using.

Comment: Is there any reason to think it isn't normal?   Is there something unusual about your environment?

Comment: SET @Sql = 'SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0''
,''Text;HDR=YES;Database='+CAST(@Path AS varchar(250))+'''
,''SELECT * FROM ['+CAST(@FileName AS varchar(250))+']'');'

EXEC(@Sql)

Comment: was under the impression that openrowset would guess the proper data type however this is not happening ... again, it's assuming that all columns are text although that's clearly not the case.  i'm generating all my tables dynamically so a format file would be inconvenient.  thanks.